# Adding custom glyph of a break point in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, breakpoints, vsix

I want to create a custom breakpoint type that will break for a duration then continue. I can mark a breakpoint as this new custom type with a command in its context. Is it possible to change the red glyph of the breakpoint to one that is blue or maybe even a different shape? I cant find any literature about it anywhere. I think I could make a custom text view port adornment for a separated breakpoint marking column but things would be less complicated if I could just change the glyph. I am working with wpf. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is possible with the IGlyphFactory.

Read this to see how its done.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-an-editor-item-template?view=vs-2019